# PHP Define Function without executing

Tags: php, function

I am currently developing an advertising module for a custom CMS, and using template tags to allow customers to add adverts into their pages through a WSYWIG page content editor.

Eg. `{=advert_1}`

On the frontend, this will be found through a regex and then be converted into a function, which will look to a database to select and display an advert

Template_tags.php

```
while ($advertRow = $advertResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $advertGroupID = $advertRow['grpID'];
    $advert = "advert_";

    ${$advert . $advertGroupID} = showAdvert($advertGroupID);
}
```

This means `{=advert_1}` will be converted to `showAdvert(1)`

The problem I am having is that the `showAdvert` function will be run for all adverts regardless of whether or not it appears on the page, which then adds to the "views", even though the advert may not be displayed.

What I want is to just define the function without executing it, so when it appears in the page content, only then will the function will be executed.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  If `{=advert_1}` is on the page then it  will be converted to `showAdvert(1)` and run.  If not, it won't be converted and won't run.  What's the prob?

Comment: Any time you use variable variables, you should really be using an array.

Comment: Because it's grabbing the `grpID` from the database, it is looping through these and creating a function for every "group", and executing each one on the line `${$advert . $advertGroupID} = showAdvert($advertGroupID);`

Comment: This is my first time using variable variables, and still find them strange. What would the array alternative be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function expression to create a closure.

```
${$advert . $advertGroupID} = function() use($advertGroupID) {
    showAdvert($advertGroupID);
};
```

To call the function, you need to put parentheses after it:

```
$name = 'advert_1';
echo $$name();
```

To use it with `preg_replace_callback`

```
preg_replace_callback("/\{=([^\{]{1,100}?)\}/", function($match) {
    return $match[1]();
}, $pageContent);
```

Comment: I got an unexpected ")" on the last line, and when I took that out I got 
"Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string".

This is was on this line
`$pageContent =  preg_replace("/\{=([^\{]{1,100}?)\}/e", "$$1", $pageContent);`

Comment: Did you get that error when you called the function? Sounds like you forgot to put `()` after the variable containing the function, so you were trying to echo the function itself instead of calling it.

Comment: I think it should be `"$$1()"` so it calls the function. BTW, you shouldn't use the `e` modifier in `preg_replace`, you should use `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: I am echoing the function, because I'm echoing out the `$pageContent` which has the template tag `{=advert_1}` in it. The `showAdvert()` function then returns the html for the advert.

Comment: But you don't want to echo the function, you want to **call** the function at that point.

Comment: I've tried swapping my `preg_replace` to `$pageContent = preg_replace_callback("/\{=([^\{]{1,100}?)\}/", "$$1()", $pageContent);` but I'm getting **Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '$$1()', to be a valid callback**

Comment: It's not a drop-in replacement. You have to provide a function as the second argument, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense now. Thanks for all your help! :)